# How to read file in matlab?

Tags: file, matlab, matrix

I have a txt file, and the content of the file is rows of numbers,
each row have 5 float number in it, with comma seperate between each number.
example:

1.1 , 12 , 1.42562, 3.5 , 2.2

2.1 , 3.3 , 3 , 3.333, 6.75

How can I read the file content into matrix in matlab?
So far I have this:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
comma  = char(',');
A = fscanf(fid, ['%f', comma]);
fclose(fid);
```

The problem is that it's only give me the first line and when I
try to write the content of A I get this:  1.0e+004 * some number

Can someone help me please?
I guess that for the file I need to read it in a loop but I don't know how.

Edit: One more question: When I do output to A I get this:

```
A =

1.0e+004 *
4.8631         0         0         0    0.0001
4.8638   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0004    0.0114
4.8647   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0008    0.0109
```

I want the same values that in the file to be in the matrix, how can I make the numbers to be regular float and not formatted like this? Or are the numbers in the matrix actually float, but the output is just displayed like this?

Comment: are you only interested in the numerical data?

Comment: yes, just the numbers.

Comment: @shlomi, you hit the nail on the head with your followup. That's just how MATLAB is displaying the data. If you look in the workspace, you can tell what format your data is actually in. Alternatively, you can type `whos` into the command prompt, and it will list out all your variables, their sizes, and their types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MATLAB's built-in [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) function would be a much easier solution for what you want to accomplish.

```
A = dlmread('filename.txt',',') % call dlmread and specify a comma as the delimiter
```

Answer (score 6):

try with using `importdata` function

```
A = importdata(`filename.txt`);
```

It will solve your question.

**EDIT**

Alternative 1)

```
A = dlmread('test_so.txt',',');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is surprisingly simple:

```
fid = fopen('depthMap.txt');
A = fscanf(fid, '%f');
fclose(fid);
```